# I am trying to integrate filebased session in django

Tags: django

I am trying to integrate filebased session in django. I have followed all the provided details But session is not working.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/django_cache',
    }
}
```

I am getting below error

```
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

no such table: django_session
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you confused [`caching`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/) and [`session`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/) frameworks. Your current settings is affecting only cache system. To use file based session you need to add `SESSION_ENGINE` and `SESSION_FILE_PATH` settings:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.file"
SESSION_FILE_PATH = "/var/tmp/django_cache"
```

Comment: It's working fine thanks. How to detect cache based session?

Comment: @Testadmin check this part of documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions